# I'm torn between conditionals and abrupt return functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, comparative-review, express.js

Which one of these two is better?

This one:

```
middleware.response_redirect = function(){
   return function (req, res, next){
       var redirect = function(){
           if(req.form.redirect) return url.parse(req.form.redirect);
           return {
               protocol: "http",
               hostname: config.domain,
               pathname: "thanks",
           }
       }();
       redirect.query = querystring.stringify({
           "status": "success",
           "message": req.form.message
       });
       return res.redirect(url.format(redirect);
   }  
}
```

Or this one:

```
middleware.response_redirect = function(){
   return function (req, res, next){
       var redirect;
       if(req.form.redirect){
           redirect = url.parse(req.form.redirect);  
       }else{
           redirect = {
               protocol: "http",
               hostname: config.domain,
               pathname: "thanks",
           }
       }
       redirect.query = querystring.stringify({
           "status": "success",
           "message": req.form.message
       });
       return res.redirect(url.format(redirect);
   }  
}
```

The function within function thing bothers me a little. But so does setting `redirect` in two places.

Answer (score 8):

How about a ternary operator?

```
var redirect = req.from.redirect
  ? url.parse(req.from.redirect)
  : {
    protocol: 'http',
    hostname: config.domain,
    pathname: 'thanks'
  };
```

Looks cleaner in my opinion.